# Karate pathMatches exclusion

Tags: karate

I would like to have possibility in Karate to match all paths except `/example/path`, to have something like this:

```
pathMatches ('!/example/path')
```

Is there such possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`requestUri`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#requesturi) variable which will be always set automatically. The nice thing about the design is you can use "normal" Java Script and achieve any combination you want, `pathMatches()` is just pre-defined for convenience.

So this should get you what you want, try it !

```
Scenario: !requestUri.startsWith('/example/path')
```

EDIT: silly me, I just realized that you have a much better option, again "because JavaScript". This will work !

```
Scenario: !pathMatches('/example/path')
```